# Comperare vs Comprare

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Up to my knowledge both "comperare" and "comprare" mean to buy or to purchase. In which context should I use one or the other, are they always interchangeable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those have the same usage, "comperare" is more old usage and used nowadays in some regions of Italy but it's accepted everywhere. "Comprare" is more common

http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/comprare/